# How to monitor remote user logged by ssh and watch what do in my linux machine

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to monitor what a remote user (whom logged by ssh) do in his terminal in my linux machine. The w command just show who logged and what he did, however I am interested to watch his activity in terminal online.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid typing `who` repeatedly, you may use the
[whowatch command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whowatch)
that watches logged in users and processes in real time.

For more details, see the article
[whowatch – Monitor Linux Users and Processes in Real Time](https://www.tecmint.com/whowatch-monitor-linux-users-and-processes-in-real-time/).

There are many other methods of logging user activity to a log file, starting from
`auditd` and going to packages like
[snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) and
[sudosh](https://github.com/cloudposse/sudosh).